# Sort hash by key as a reverse order, return hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash, reverse

Can you please help anyone?. I have a hash value as following. I need to sort the hash in reverse order by key value and return as also hash type.

**My actual expected output is (hash)**

```
result = {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

```
# this is my input
irb(main):096:0> h = {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9]} 
=> {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9]}

# It's not correct
irb(main):095:0> Hash[h.sort]
=> {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9]}
```

So, i tried this. It's correct but it's return as a array value, i need a return value as Hash.

```
# It's correct but it's not a hash
irb(main):092:0> arr = h.sort_by { |k,v| k }.reverse
=> [[20111104111221, [4, 5, 6]], [20111104111220, [7, 8, 9]], [20111104110950, [1, 2, 3]]]
```

Again i tried array to hash conversion.. but it's help.

```
# It's also not correct.
irb(main):092:0> irb(main):098:0> Hash[*arr.flatten]
=> {5=>6, 20111104111221=>4, 20111104110950=>1, 2=>3, 8=>9, 20111104111220=>7}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of ruby are you using? In 1.8 hashes cannot be ordered, in 1.9 they are ordered based on insertion. Here's [more info on that](http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/).

Given the variation in how they're handled I wouldn't focus on sorting the hash itself, but on sorting your keys and using them as a reference, something like:

```
data = {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3]}

keys = data.keys.sort.reverse
keys.each do |key|
  puts data[key].pretty_inspect
  # ... do work ...
end
```

The debug line is in there just as an example of how to access your values. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

You're almost there with `h.sort_by...`, don't flatten that just feed it to `Hash[]`:

```
Hash[h.sort_by { |k,v| -k }]
```

I also simplified your sorting, negating the number does the same thing as sorting and reversing.

For example:

```
>> h = {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9]}
=> {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9]}
>> Hash[h.sort_by { |k,v| -k }]
=> {20111104111221=>[4, 5, 6], 20111104111220=>[7, 8, 9], 20111104110950=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: Thanks @mu. It's not working for me. The second statement returns the original value of h.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ruby 1.8.7 version.

Comment: @Mr.Black: Then you want Matt's workaround for unordered hashes in 1.8.